# Angular $http gives XORS error, jQuery $ajax is okay

Tags: jquery, ajax, angularjs, cross-domain

So basically as the title says. Here is the problem, first part where I do $http call gives me x-domain error. The second part where I use jquery ajax call works perfectly fine and returns array of data.

Can someone suggest why is this happening? I really would like to use $http and native angular methods.
Thanks for help!

[image]

Comment: angularjs have [jsonp](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#jsonp)

Comment: there is already jsonp @ArunPJohny

Comment: can you share the url used

Comment: @ArunPJohnny
It involves API key. I haven't got that key myself, so not sure if I can share it.
The second part is from already working code and the server returns plain JSON if i send a 'GET' with any kind of 'POSTman' chrome plugin or anything else capable of sending requests. So I am not sure about 'jsonp' here

Answer (score 0):

you have to append jsonp=JSON_CALLBACK at the end of urls:

```
var url = 'http://yoururl' + '&jsonp=JSON_CALLBACK';

$http.jsonp(url).then(function (data) 
{

});
```